# Using jest for unit test in vuejs + laravel

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

Inside my vue js component, I have this

```
<template>
    <div class="timing_fund_redirect">Your fund will drop in {{ timer }} seconds.</div>
</template>
```

How can I unit test that part in Jest

assuming I have

```
methods: {
            fundTimer() {
                var countdown = 10;

                window.setInterval(function() {
                    (countdown < 1) ? window.location = _this.path : _this.timer = countdown;
                    countdown--;
                },1000);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want to test time-based javascript using Jest, you can use [timer mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html). If you want to test that you're setting your "timer" data property correctly, that would be relatively easy to test:

```
import Timer from './Timer.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('it works', () => {
   it('sets the timer property correctly', () => {
      jest.runTimersToTime(3000);
      // remember to call this in a nextTick callback so your component has a change to update properly
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        // you don't do your first reduction of the property until one second is elapsed, so after 3 seconds, timer will equal 8
        expect(Timer.data().timer).toBe(8) 
      }) 
   }
});
```

As far as testing whether your redirect works, you could just run the timer to a number over your threshold of 10 seconds using `runTimersToTime`. It's a little tricky to mock the window.location object itself, but I usually like to abstract URL redirects into a separate module anyway, so you could do that, and then spy on your redirect method to make sure it was called.

I assume you're using `_this` so you can access your Vue component in the scope of your `setTimeout` callback, though I don't see where you set it. 
You could just use an arrow function to allow you to access the component's data property inside that callback.

Furthermore, you don't really need the local `countdown` variable, you can just modify the timer property directly.

```
data () {
  return {
    timer: 10
  }
},
methods: {
  fundTimer() {
     window.setInterval(() => {
        (this.timer < 1) ? window.location = this.path : this.timer--;
     },1000);
  }
}
```